# Geodesics on a curved cylinder

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, geodesic

I think I've done everything correct, but I'd like to have a second pair of eyes to look at it. So enjoy the calculations!

Consider the curved cylinder with the parametrisation

$$F:\mathbb{R}\times[0,2\pi)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3,\quad F(t,\phi)=\big((1+t^2)\cos\phi,(1+t^2)\sin\phi,t\big)$$

It basically looks like the left of those cylinders

[image]

I calculate the tangent and normal vectors:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{dF}{dt}&= (2t\cos\phi,2t\sin\phi,1)\\
\frac{dF}{d\phi}&=(1+t^2)(-\sin\phi,\cos\phi,0)\\
\frac{d^2F}{dt^2}&=2(\cos\phi,\sin\phi,0)\\
\frac{d^2F}{dtd\phi}&=2t(-\sin\phi,\cos\phi,0)\\
\frac{d^2F}{d\phi^2}&=-(1+t^2)(\cos\phi,\sin\phi,0)\\
\frac{dF}{dt}\times\frac{dF}{d\phi}&=-(1+t^2)(\cos\phi,\sin\phi,-2t)\\
\|\frac{dF}{dt}\times\frac{dF}{d\phi}\|&=(1+t^2)\sqrt{1+4t^2}\\
N\circ F&=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4t^2}}(\cos\phi,\sin\phi,-2t)
\end{align}
$$

For the first and second fundamental form and the curvatures I find

$$
\begin{align}
g&=\begin{pmatrix}
1+4t^2 & 0\\
0 & (1+t^2)^2
\end{pmatrix}\\
h&=\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+4t^2}} & 0\\
0 & \frac{1+t^2}{\sqrt{1+4t^2}}
\end{pmatrix}\\
K&=\frac{\det(h)}{\det(g)}=-\frac{2}{(1+4t^2)(1+t^2)}\\
H&=\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{trace}(hg^{-1})=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2t^2-1}{(1+4t^2)^\frac{3}{2}(1+t^2)}
\end{align}
$$

And for the Christoffel-symbols

$$
\begin{align}
\Gamma^1_{11}&=\frac{4t}{1+4t^2}\\
\Gamma^1_{12}=\Gamma^1_{21}&=0\\
\Gamma^1_{22}&=-\frac{2t(1+t^2)}{1+4t^2}\\
\Gamma^2_{11}&=0\\
\Gamma^2_{12}=\Gamma^2_{21}&=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\\
\Gamma^2_{22}&=0\\
\end{align}
$$

The covariant vectors are

$$
\begin{align}
\nabla_{\frac{dF}{dt}}\frac{dF}{dt}&=\Gamma^1_{11}\frac{dF}{dt}+\Gamma^2_{11}\frac{dF}{d\phi}=\frac{4t}{1+4t^2}\frac{dF}{dt}\\
\nabla_{\frac{dF}{dt}}\frac{dF}{d\phi}=\nabla_{\frac{dF}{d\phi}}\frac{dF}{dt}&=\Gamma^1_{12}\frac{dF}{dt}+\Gamma^2_{12}\frac{dF}{d\phi}=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\frac{dF}{d\phi}\\
\nabla_{\frac{dF}{d\phi}}\frac{dF}{d\phi}&=\Gamma^1_{22}\frac{dF}{dt}+\Gamma^2_{22}\frac{dF}{d\phi}=-\frac{2t(1+t^2)}{1+4t^2}\frac{dF}{dt}\\
\end{align}$$

**Question:** Can I use those covariant vectors to calculate a geodesic?

Now I check if the meridian and the latitudes are geodesics

$$c(t)=F(t,\phi)=F(\tilde{c}(t))$$
with
$$\tilde{c}_1(t)=t,\quad \tilde{c}_2(t)=\phi$$
The derivates are
$$\tilde{c}_1'(t)=1,\quad \tilde{c}_2'(t)=0$$
$$\tilde{c}_1''(t)=0,\quad \tilde{c}_2''(t)=0$$
Therefore the geodesics equations

$$\tilde{c}_k''(t)+\Gamma^k_{ij}(\tilde{c}(t))\tilde{c}_i'(t)\tilde{c}_j'(t)$$
simplify to

$$
\begin{align}
\Gamma^1_{11}(t,\phi)&=\frac{4t}{1+4t^2}\ne 0\\
\Gamma^2_{11}(t,\phi)&=0
\end{align}$$

Therefore the meridians are no geodesics

Now I do the same for the latitudes:

$$c(\phi)=F(t,\phi)=F(\tilde{c}(\phi))$$
with
$$\tilde{c}_1(\phi)=t,\quad \tilde{c}_2(\phi)=\phi$$
The derivates are
$$\tilde{c}_1'(\phi)=0,\quad \tilde{c}_2'(\phi)=1$$
$$\tilde{c}_1''(\phi)=0,\quad \tilde{c}_2''(\phi)=0$$
Therefore the geodesics equations

$$\tilde{c}_k''(\phi)+\Gamma^k_{ij}(\tilde{c}(\phi))\tilde{c}_i'(\phi)\tilde{c}_j'(\phi)$$
simplify to

$$
\begin{align}
\Gamma^1_{22}(t,\phi)&=-\frac{2t(1+t^2)}{1+4t^2}\\
\Gamma^2_{22}(t,\phi)&=0
\end{align}$$

For the latitude at $t=0$, I find that both equations vanish. Therefore the latitude $$c_0(\phi):=F(0,\phi)$$
is a geodesic.

Finally I want to calculate the geodesic curvature of the latitude at $t=1$, i.e. the value

$$\kappa_g=\langle\frac{\nabla}{d\phi}\gamma'(\phi),\eta(\phi)\rangle$$

where $\gamma$ is the same curve as $F(1,\cdot)$, but parametrised by arclength.

Define the curve $$c(\phi)=F(1,\phi)=F(\tilde{c}(\phi))$$

with

$$\tilde{c}_1(\phi)=1,\quad \tilde{c}_2(\phi)=\phi$$

First, the derivates are

$$\tilde{c}_1'(\phi)=0,\quad \tilde{c}_2'(\phi)=1$$

I calculate the first derivative and check if it is parametrised by arclength:

$$c'(\phi)=\frac{d}{ds}F(\tilde{c}(\phi+s))\big|_{s=0}=\frac{dF}{d\phi}(\tilde{c}(\phi))$$

$$\|c'(\phi)\|^2=g_{22}(\tilde{c}(\phi))=(1+t^2)^2\big|_{\tilde{c}(\phi)=(1,\phi)}=4\ne 1$$

Now parametrise this curve by arclength:

$$\alpha^{-1}(\phi):=\int_0^\phi 2ds=2\phi$$
has the inverse function

$$\alpha(\phi)=\frac{\phi}{2}$$

with derivative

$$\alpha'(\phi)=\frac{1}{2}$$

Define the curve $\gamma:=c\circ\alpha$, which is parametrised by arclength. Its derivates are

$$\begin{align}
\gamma'(\phi)&=\alpha'(\phi)c'(\alpha(\phi))=\frac{1}{2}\frac{dF}{d\phi}(\tilde{c}(\alpha(\phi)))\\
\gamma''(\phi)&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{ds}\frac{dF}{d\phi}(\tilde{c}\circ\alpha(\phi+s))\big|_{s=0}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\langle\operatorname{grad}\frac{dF}{d\phi}(\tilde{c}(\alpha(\phi)),\tilde{c}'(\alpha(\phi))\cdot\alpha'(\phi)\rangle\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\frac{d^2F}{d\phi^2}(\tilde{c}(\alpha(\phi)))
\end{align}$$

And the covariant derivate is

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\nabla}{d\phi}\gamma'(\phi)
&=\frac{1}{4}\Big(\Gamma^1_{22}\frac{dF}{dt}+\Gamma^2_{22}\frac{dF}{d\phi}\Big)(\tilde{c}(\alpha(\phi)))\\
&=\Big(\frac{1}{4}(-\frac{2t(1+t^2)}{1+4t^2})\frac{dF}{dt}\Big)(1,\frac{\phi}{2})\\
&=-\frac{1}{5}\frac{dF}{dt}(\tilde{c}(\alpha(\phi)))
\end{align}$$

Since $g_{12}=g_{21}=0$ and $(\frac{dF}{d\phi},-\frac{dF}{dt})$ is apositive oriented base of the tangent space, I choose

$$\eta(\phi)=-\|\frac{dF}{dt}\|^{-1}\cdot\frac{dF}{dt}(\tilde{c}(\alpha(\phi)))=-\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4t^2}}\frac{dF}{dt}\Big)(\tilde{c}(\alpha(\phi)))=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\frac{dF}{dt}(\tilde{c}(\alpha(\phi)))$$

as a united speed normal vector, such that
$$(\gamma',\eta)$$ forms a positive oriented orthogonal base of the tangent space.

Finally I calulate

$$
\begin{align}
\kappa_g
&=\langle\frac{\nabla}{d\phi}\gamma'(\phi),\eta(\phi)\rangle\\
&=\Big(-\frac{1}{5}\Big)\Big(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\Big)\langle\frac{dF}{dt},\frac{dF}{dt}\rangle(\tilde{c}(\alpha(\phi)))\\
&=\Big(-\frac{1}{5}\Big)\Big(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\Big)g_{11}(\tilde{c}(\alpha(\phi)))\\
&=\Big(-\frac{1}{5}\Big)\Big(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\Big)\Big(1+4t^2\Big)\Big|_{\tilde{c}(\alpha(\phi)))=(1,\frac{\Phi}{2})}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}
\end{align}
$$

If anyone has been reading until here, I am very grateful for your attention! Feel free to make any reply or comment on my post. Especially if you find, that anything is wrong, I would be very happy, to hear from you. Also if you find that the calculations are right, I'd be happy for a short reply. :-)

Thanks again for your attention!

Comment: I have not read the details, hut meridians will always be geodesics, so you'd better check your computations. Also read up on Clairaut's Theorem for geodesics on a surface of revolution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do I need to parametrise meridians by arclength, if I want to check that it is a geodesic? Probably the "geodesic equations" are wrong? Because I can see you are right by using the geodesics curvature.

Comment: Yes, a geodesic must be a constant-speed curve. If you want another source to read, download my free text, linked in my profile.